# Weird behavior of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when using Dropbox auth

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

The user starts in activity A and can go to activities B and C from there.

Activity C uses the Dropbox Core API to sync data between our app and Dropbox, so when the user goes to C, it starts the Dropbox authentication mechanism, which opens the Chrome browser, where the user can enter his Dropbox credentials and allow the app to access his Dropbox contents. Then, the browser invokes activity C again, where the syncing happens. After that, we want activity A to be shown again:

```
      ---->  C  ---> Chrome (Dropbox sign-in)
A  <
      ---->  B
```

### Option 1

The first option we tried is by calling `finish()` in activity C, so it would pop off the activity stack and activity A is shown again.

**Problem:** If we do that, Android does not show activity A again, but the browser, where the user previously signed in to Dropbox. So it seems the stack at the moment of `finish()` is:

```
A  ---->  C  ---> Chrome (Dropbox sign-in)  ---->  C
```

and not

```
A  ---->  C
```

### Option 2

So we tried it by starting an `Intent` with activity A and `FLAGS_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, so all activities are cleared off the stack:

```
A  ---->  C  ---> Chrome (Dropbox sign-in)  ---->  C

 |
 V

A
```

**Problem:** If the user then goes to activity B and presses the back button there, activity C is shown again.

**Doesn't `FLAGS_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` mean that activity C is cleared off the stack? How can I achieve what I want?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using a combination of options 1 and 2 seems to work:

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This finishes activity C and at the same time creates a new intent to show activity A.

After that, the activity stack seems like we want it to be: no activity C popping up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things for that :

1. You need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the intent starting **Activity C**.
2. In your manifest file make **Activity C** `launchMode = "singleTop"`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Using option 1, we still see the Chrome browser when doing `finish()` in activity C. Using option 2, activity C is shown when pressing the back button in activity B.